# Is array[x, y] a valid C expression?

Tags: arrays, c, gcc

When referring to the following doc on macros https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC12, I see array[x, y] being passed as an argument. Is it a valid C expression? If so what does it do?

Comment: Yes, but it evaluates and discards `x` and uses `y` as the array index.

Comment: It uses [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) and is perfectly valid. I'd argue that it's most commonly used to confuse beginners. :)

Comment: Compare to: `int n = x, y;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the relevant code in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC12) is discussing the minutiae of how arguments to macros are processed:

> Parentheses in the actual arguments must balance; a comma within parentheses does not end an argument. However, there is no requirement for brackets or braces to balance, and they do not prevent a comma from separating arguments. Thus,
>
> ```
> macro (array[x = y, x + 1])
> ```
>
> passes two arguments to macro: `array[x = y` and `x + 1]`. If you want to supply `array[x = y, x + 1]` as an argument, you must write it as `array[(x = y, x + 1)]`, which is equivalent C code.

Also, note that the GCC version 2.95 documentation is very old (dating back to [1999](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)).  You should not normally need to consult that these days.  That said, this aspect has not changed in the interim.

As noted in the comments, outside of the context of a macro, the notation:

```
array[x = y, x + 1]
```

uses a comma operator to evaluate the LHS (the assignment `x = y`), and then uses the RHS (the expression `x + 1`) as the index to the array.  Without some statement with side effects (such as an assignment or perhaps a function call), the notation is pointless.  It is, however, well defined.  And there is a sequence point between the evaluation of the LHS and RHS of the comma operator, which is important in the example.